# When I create an ICON resource, will the .RES file contains two entries?

Tags: winapi, embedded-resource

I have created a .RES file from this resource script:

```
my_icon ICON D:\1.ico
```

When I open the .RES file in Resource Hacker, I get two entries for the icon:

[image]

Does the .RES file contains these two entries (Icon and Icon Group) or does Resource Hacker create one of these two entries just for convenience? and which one does Resource Hacker creates if this is the case?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/20/10331787.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that Resource Hacker doen't visualize the icon structure in a good way.

Each icon causes an icon group to be created. It is a structure that points to all stored images in the icon.

I guess that resource hacker visualizes the targets on which the group icon entries point in this way.

The format is explained in detail in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/20/10331787.aspx) and off course in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648007(v=vs.85).aspx)